# Hive parse and edit array to struct field

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, user-defined-functions, hiveql

I've a requirement in hive complex data structure which I'm new to. I've tried few things which didn't work out. I'd like to know if there is a solution or I'm looking at a dead end.
Requirement : 
Table1 and Table2 are of same create syntax. I want to select all columns from table1 and insert it into table2, where few column values will be modified. For struct field also, I can make it work using named_struct. 
But if table1 has array> type, then I'm not sure how to make it work.

eg.,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
   ID              INT,
   XYZ             array<STRUCT<X:DOUBLE, Y:DOUBLE, Z:DOUBLE>> 
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '$' 
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '#' ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
   ID              INT,
   XYZ             array<STRUCT<X:DOUBLE, Y:DOUBLE, Z:DOUBLE>> 
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '$' 
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '#' ;

hive> select * from table1 ;
OK
1       [{"x":1,"y":2,"z":3},{"x":4,"y":5,"z":6},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":9}]
2       [{"x":4,"y":5,"z":6},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":9}]
```

How can I update a struct field in array while inserting. Let's say if structField y is 5, then I want it to be inserted as 0.

Answer (score 2):

For complex type struct you can use [Brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Downloads) UDF.Download the jar and add it in your script.

```
add jar hdfs://path_where_jars_are_downloaded/brickhouse-0.6.0.jar
```

Create a collect function.

```
create temporary function collect_arrayofstructs as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';
```

Query:Replace the y value with 0

```
select ID, collect_arrayofstructs( 
         named_struct(
           "x", x,
           "y", 0,
           "z", z,
           )) as XYZ
  from table1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. But what you have suggested is a UDAF. I don't want to perform a group by. I just want to pass an array and get and updated array as output.